# multidimensional arrays arrays inside an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Data Structure is my weakness and I want to get a deeper understanding on it. would appreciate some clarification here.

```
sandwiches = [["cheese", "ham"], ["avocado", "bacon"], ["tomato","pesto","cheese","mayo"], ["egg"], ["turkey", "ketchup", "mustard"]]
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. thanks!

Inside sandwiches, there is 1 array.
Inside the sub-sandwiches array, there are 5 arrays.

But I'm stuck on understanding how many elements there are in the sandwiches array and the sub sandwiches array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ruby itself to figure out the answer to such questions:

```
sandwiches.map(&:length)
#=> [2, 2, 4, 1, 3]
```

This gives you the length of each array nested in `sandwiches`.

Note that `.map(&:length)` is the short version of `.map { |x| x.length }`.

Answer (score 2):

The sandwiches array contains 5 elements (and each of these elements is also an array):

```
sandwiches = [
["cheese", "ham"], #first element of sandwiches -> an array with 2 elements (cheese and ham)
["avocado", "bacon"], #second element of sandwiches, an array with 2 elements (avocado and bacon)
["tomato","pesto","cheese","mayo"], # third element of sandwiches, an array with 4 elements (tomato, pesto, cheese and mayo)
["egg"], # fourth element of sandwiches, an array with one element (egg)
["turkey", "ketchup", "mustard"] # fifth element of sandwiches, an array with 3 elements (turkey, ketchup and mustard)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 1major array with 5 elements [0,1,2,3,4]

Element at position 0 is another array with 2 elements

Element at position 1 is another array with 2 elements too

Element at position 2 is another array with 4 elements

Element at position 3 is another array with 1 element

Element at position 4 is another array with 3 elements

Ps: u can consider a position each element separated by comas (,)

i.e:  [ fisrt_element,  second_element,  [fist_element_of_this_arry, second_element_of_this_arry], fourth_element]

so the array above is one major array with 4 elements and element 3 is an array with two elements:   [0,1, [ 0,1], 3]

remember that array position aways begin from 0